# Scipy ckdtree - boxsize parameter

Tags: python, scipy, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I am using the ckdtree for nearest neighbour searches. I have a box of randomly distributed points. I want the box to be periodic and search for all the neighbours within a sphere of given radius r around a point.

I'm doing this for a large number of points and with increasing radii. I then calculate the average number density of points. One would assume that if the box is periodic, the density within the sphere should approach the density of the whole box, so the total number of points within the box divided by the box size cubed. This however doesn't happen. The density within the sphere approaches the density of the box at a radius if about 1/5th of the the boxsize and then steadly decreases. When the radius of the sphere is half the boxsize, the density is already only 1/5th of the actual density of the box.

Does the boxsize function not make the box periodic in the way I think or is there a mistake somewhere else in my thinking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please consider showing us your code.

Comment: I assume your data is in 3 dimensions?